# If able, wrap words, if not, break them. Resize iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, word-wrap

How can I make that if able, wrap words, if not, break them, in an iframe? I need it to be in an iframe that is used to write.

And when the words do not enter any more, resize automaticly so that all can be seen

```
<Iframe style="resize:auto;" contenteditable="true" name="richTextEdit"></iframe>

<Script>

Window.onload = richTextEdit.document.designMode = 'On';
```

Comment: I'm sorry, i've tried something like this

Comment: I've thought like getting the rows and making the iframe the rows height but i didnt know how to do it

Comment: Cause it was the easiest way to make a text editor with the options of bold and the rest

Comment: It's a text editor and with a div with contenteditable didnt work